# Have menu buttons centered css dropdown menu

Tags: css, css-float, center

I am using this css for styling my menu.  The menu `li`'s are currently set to `float: left` which obviously positions them to the left, however I would really like them centred in the middle.

**Could anyone help me with modifying this please?**

```
.menu{

border:none;
border:0px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
}
.menu ul{

background:#6991B7;
height:35px;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}
.menu li{

    float:left;
    padding:0px;

    }
.menu li a{
    background:#6991B7 url("images/seperator.gif") bottom right no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:35px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 25px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    .menu li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover a{
        background: #2580a2 url("images/hover.gif") bottom center no-repeat;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
.menu li ul{
    background:#333333;
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:225px;
    z-index:200;
    /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/
    }
.menu li:hover ul{
    display:block;

    }
.menu li li {
    background:url('images/sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:225px;
    }
.menu li:hover li a{
    background:none;

    }
.menu li ul a{
    display:block;
    height:35px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:normal;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align:left;
    }
    .menu li ul a:hover, .menu li ul li:hover a{
        background:#2580a2 url('images/hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
        border:0px;
        color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
.menu p{
    clear:left;
    }
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like for your navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i think you want to that your navi is show center check to this code i have some modify in your css code

```
1. text-align:center put to .menu css
2. .menu li, .menu li a define to display:inline-block;
3. .menu ul define margin: 0 auto; and overflow:hidden;
```

**Css**

```
    .menu{

border:none;
border:0px;
margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;
font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
.menu ul{

background:#6991B7;
height:35px;
list-style:none;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.menu li{

    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;

    }
.menu li a{
    background:#6991B7 url("images/seperator.gif") bottom right no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:35px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 25px;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    .menu li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover a{
        background: #2580a2 url("images/hover.gif") bottom center no-repeat;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
.menu li ul{
    background:#333333;
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:225px;
    z-index:200;
    /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/
    }
.menu li:hover ul{
    display:block;

    }
.menu li li {
    background:url('images/sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:225px;
    }
.menu li:hover li a{
    background:none;

    }
.menu li ul a{
    display:block;
    height:35px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:normal;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align:left;
    }
    .menu li ul a:hover, .menu li ul li:hover a{
        background:#2580a2 url('images/hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
        border:0px;
        color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
.menu p{
    clear:left;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Demo link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Demo link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Demo link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Demo link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Demo link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Demo link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/g3hLK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `margin: 0 auto;` on `.menu li a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your menu `li` elements as `display:inline-block` instead and then have your menu container center them automatically by using the `text-align:center` property like so:

```
.menu{
    border:none;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}

.menu li{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    padding:0px;
}
```